# Spark history for Standalone Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have seen this text on Spark website. I am trying to view Spark logs on the UI even after application ended or killed.
Is there anyway that i could view the logs in Standalone mode?

Spark is run on Mesos or YARN, it is still possible to construct the UI of an application through Spark’s history server, provided that the application’s event logs exist. You can start the history server by executing:

```
./sbin/start-history-server.sh
This creates a web interface at http://<server-url>:18080 by default, listing incomplete and completed applications and attempts.

When using the file-system provider class (see spark.history.provider below), the base logging directory must be supplied in the spark.history.fs.logDirectory configuration option, and should contain sub-directories that each represents an application’s event logs.

The spark jobs themselves must be configured to log events, and to log them to the same shared, writeable directory. For example, if the server was configured with a log directory of hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs, then the client-side options would be:

spark.eventLog.enabled true spark.eventLog.dir hdfs://namenode/shared/spark-logs
```

Comment: Yes , After enabling history server you could view the logs.